# Removing a parent tag of a string until his closing tag from Html string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

i have a very long string, what i am, trying to accomplish is delete a section in that string from the `<tr>` parent tag of the string to his closing tag `</tr>`. (hope i am clear enough).

So when i call The method RemoveSection with the text "Search Integration"

---

### Html before

```
  <tr>
    <td class=\"SectionHeaderHolder\" colspan=\"4\">
    <p class=\"SectionHeader\">Header XX<span class=\"help\">Help</span></p>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class=\"SectionHeaderHolder\" colspan=\"4\">
    <p class=\"SectionHeader\">Search Integration<span class=\"help\">Help</span></p>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class=\"SectionHeaderHolder\" colspan=\"4\">
    <p class=\"SectionHeader\">Header YY<span class=\"help\">Help</span></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

---

- The string that Remove function gets will be under `<p class=\"SectionHeader\">`
- There will be only one section with that string- so the first occurrence should be handled by the remove function.

---

### Html after

```
 <tr>
    <td class=\"SectionHeaderHolder\" colspan=\"4\">
    <p class=\"SectionHeader\">Header XX<span class=\"help\">Help</span></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
    <td class=\"SectionHeaderHolder\" colspan=\"4\">
    <p class=\"SectionHeader\">Header YY<span class=\"help\">Help</span></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) for this. A simple LinqPad example:

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "<tr><td class=\"SectionHeaderHolder\" colspan=\"4\"><p class=\"SectionHeader\">Header XX<span class=\"help\">Help</span></p></td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td class=\"SectionHeaderHolder\" colspan=\"4\">    <p class=\"SectionHeader\">Search Integration<span class=\"help\">Help</span></p>    </td>    </tr>"
                + "<tr><td class=\"SectionHeaderHolder\" colspan=\"4\">    <p class=\"SectionHeader\">Header YY<span class=\"help\">Help</span></p>    </td>    </tr>";

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(input);

    doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p[text()='Search Integration']").ParentNode.ParentNode.Remove();

    string output = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

    input.Dump();
    output.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'd still recommend the accepted solution, same thing can be done using plain regex

```
string search = "Search Integration";

string pattern = "<tr(?:(?!/?<tr).)*" + search + "(?:(?!/?tr).)*/tr>";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
string result = r.Replace(text, "");
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OcV6E5